# What does it mean?

Tags: grammar

I was born sensing my limitation as a human being.

What does it mean?
Does this mean I was born while senseing my limitation?

Comment: Where does this sentence come from?

Comment: It's more like I could sense (feel) my limitation from the moment I was born. "born while sensing" means that he was sitting there in the womb sensing, then he started to be born at the same time.

Comment: A quick Google for that quote shows this question as the only place using that phrase. The phrase as it stands is very poor English, so I'm closing this question as "unclear what you're asking" until you cite your quote or give some additional context.

Answer (score 1):

The word is spelled *sensing*, and yes, the speaker of the sentence sensed his limitation. Many verbs in English that end with *-e* drop the *e* before adding *-ing*.

I can't help much with the philosophical meaning, however.

Answer (score -1):

The typical progression is that someone is born relatively helpless and without much ability and that they develop abilities over time.  The writer is saying that *at the time I was born I already  had a sense of the limitations imposed on me as a human being.*

Of course you'll have to take that figuratively because I don't know anyone who was capable of introspective thought straight out of the womb.  Well ok, maybe Charles Wallace.